# Mysql workbench autoincrement id

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I use mysql workbench and i tried to automatically reset the id number after a product is deleted and under the opitons - general options tab - autoincrement i set the value to 1 but it resets it to other number like 29-30

Comment: Tell us how and maybe even why you did this

Comment: I want to make the id number automatically reset , lets say we have 3 entries in the database and 1.2.3 if i delete the 3 entry the id of the next entry will be 4 not 3 and it will be like id 1.2.4

Comment: Dont even bother trying. You will eventually bugger up your database doing anything like that